# how to get a mail in windows forms that means pop3 coding

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c)

i was checked out for sending a email....it was working....but i want to know how to receive a email in my windows forms

Comment: What does "i was checked out for sending a email." mean?

Comment: Boss stood behind him with a large ruler in her hand.  Nobody got hurt.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236381/integrating-pop3-client-functionality-into-a-c-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirement there are several POP3 libraries that do the job just fine (see below). If you only need to do very, very simple things (like - checking for new mail and displaying a "You got Mail!" (TM) baloon or displaying the count of mails on the server) I'd even say "Look at the [RFC 1939](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html)".

POP3 is text based and consists of only a handful commands. It might be as easy as sending a USER, PASS and STAT to the server to accomplish what you want.
If you're building a complete mail client though you're probably better off looking at an existing implementation and focussing on your application's functionality without spending much time on the protocol.

Some results for "C# POP3 libraries":

- http://www.spartanweb.co.uk/dotNet/mail.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/pop3library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The way you can done is by having your application to get the email by connecting to the mailbox on the server using pop3.

you can use the Afterlogic Mailbee.net Objects to retrieve email from a pop3 server.It is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

For POP3 one of the best libraries I've used is [Indy Sockets](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/index.EN.aspx). It's been around since Delphi 4 so is very mature - a grandaddy of the Open Source world. It has since been rewritten as a .NET library and provides you with APIs for

- POP3
- SMTP (if you don't want to use `System.Net`)
- IMAP 4

You could write your own POP3 library if the specification excites you, but you'll be reinventing what is now a Formula One wheel with gold plated alloys on it.