# I am having trouble gaining programmatic access to my inbox

Tags: c#, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrating POP3 client functionality into a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236381/integrating-pop3-client-functionality-into-a-c-sharp-application)

I need to dump all email sent to a distribution list (news@mycompany.com) to SQL Server. I have access to the POP3 server and have all the emails stored in my Gmail inbox. Logically the problem is simple, all I need to do is find all emails in my Gmail account OR on the POP3 server sent to `news@mycompany.com` or has `[MyCompany News]` in the subject.

I am having trouble gaining programmatic access to my inbox however. I have tried using multiple libraries such as `Google.GData.Client.dll` and `OpenPop.Pop3` with no luck. Have you done this before? Do you have any suggestions?