# C# embedded smtp server

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I am trying to find library which provides embedded lightweight SMTP server for mail receiving with .NET API. Features I am looking for: Events (e.g. OnReceived), Basic configuration (port, domain), MIME parsing (for easy subject or message body retreival). The only viable solution I have found is Rnwood.SmtpServer which does not provide MIME parsing and randomly crashes on certain emails. I have also came across multiple solutions like Papercut and netDumbster which are for testing purposes thus not having everything I need. Is there any solution I have missed?

Comment: Are you looking to send (SMTP) or receive (POP3) emails?

Comment: I am looking for receiving email sent through SMTP.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236381/integrating-pop3-client-functionality-into-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: Maybe I can use MIME parser from OpenPop.NET but that is not what I am looking for. I want SMTP server listening port 25 and receiving emails embedded in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using netDumbster with slightly modified source code with added event support. It is available here https://github.com/Inkp/netDumbster. It has been working without any significant problems so far. It still lacks full MIME-parser, though.

Comment: this is a fake smtp server, it can not really post email, how can you do?

Comment: my use case was receiving email, not posting it.

Answer (score -1):

Rnwood.SmtpServer + SharpMimeTools.

Check out the Rnwood.Smtp4Dev project to see how to extract all the stuff using SharpMimeTools library.